# Drawing y = sin(θ) * cos(θ) in C# with a Pen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, math, drawing

I want to draw `sin(θ)*cos(θ)`, but it doesn't work.
I can draw *sin* or *cos*,
but I want to draw `sin(θ)*cos(θ)` together.

Here is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Graphics drw = this.CreateGraphics();
   Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 7.0f);
   float x1 = 0;
   float y1 = 0;
   float xoy = 200;
   float ef = 20;

   for (double  i=0;i<40;i+=1)
   {
      double radi = (float)(i * 180 / Math.PI);
      float temp = (float)Math.Cos(radi)*(float)Math.Sin(radi);
      drw.DrawLine(pen, x1 * ef, y1 * ef + xoy, ef * (float)i, temp * ef + xoy);
      x1 = (float)i;
      y1 = temp;
    }
}
```

And I want this result:
[image]

Comment: please, post too your result. Thanks

Comment: Using the double angle sine formula: `sin(θ)cos(θ) = 1⁄2 sin(2θ)`. Just draw a sine curve as you did before, with *double* the input parameter, and plot *half* the resulting value. Your graphing calculator probably mis-interpreted `y` as the *radial* coordinate rather than the vertical coordinate in Cartesian charts; if you try to plot `y = sin(x)*cos(x)` it should give your *intended* result.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the real function you are looking for is a little bit different... see an example [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(sin(theta)%20*%20cos(theta))%20-%20r%20%3D%200). Looking at [this article](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/379275/flowerpower-drawing-in-polar-coordinates-in-c) about polar flowers, I'm sure it will get pointed to the right direction, and it also contains a full working source code.

Just an example, supposing you use a panel in your form on which to draw the polar flower:

```
panel.OnPaint += Panel_Paint;

private void Panel_Paint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Double scale = ((Panel)sender).Width / 2.0d;
    Double repetitions = Math.Round(scale, 0);
    Double basis = (2.0d * Math.PI) / scale;
    Double petals = 2.0d;

    using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2.0f))
        {
            for (Double i = 0.0f; i < (repetitions - 1); ++i)
            {
                Double t0 = i*basis;
                Double t1 = (i + 1)*basis;

                Double x0 = Math.Sin(petals * t0) * Math.Cos(t0);
                Double x1 = Math.Sin(petals * t1) * Math.Cos(t1);

                Double y0 = Math.Sin(petals * t0) * Math.Sin(t0);
                Double y1 = Math.Sin(petals * t1) * Math.Sin(t1);

                g.DrawLine
                    (
                        pen,
                        (Single) ((scale*x0) + scale),
                        (Single) ((scale*y0) + scale),
                        (Single) ((scale*x1) + scale),
                        (Single) ((scale*y1) + scale)
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The basic formulation states that if the `petals` variable value is:

- **even**, then it represents half the amount of petals of the polar flower
- **odd**, then it represents the amount of petals of the polar flower

so if you define `Double petals = 2.0d;`, you will obtain `4` petals... and if you define `Double petals = 5.0d;`, you will obtain `5` petals.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to look at the corresponding **[Parametric Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics))**.

[image]

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;

        double pi = Math.PI;
        int n = 100;
        var t = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(p => p * 2 * pi / n).ToArray();
        var x = t.Select(p => Math.Sin(2 * p) * Math.Cos(p)).ToArray();
        var y = t.Select(p => Math.Sin(2 * p) * Math.Sin(p)).ToArray();

        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3);

        int scale = 100;
        int shift = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, scale*(float)x[i] + shift, 
                scale*(float)y[i] + shift, 
                scale*(float)x[i + 1] + shift, 
                scale*(float)y[i + 1] + shift);
        }
    }
```